# Setting up a socket.io server on SAP HCP using Java EE and Netty-Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, jakarta-ee, sap-business-technology-platform

I have a productive HCP set up and would like to get it running as a socket.io server. I have been able to get websockets working, however I already have a lot of software running socket.io and don't want to change all of it.

I'm basically hoping to swap out the node server I have now with the HCP one. I have a java web EE project running locally which uses this https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio
This works and I can run the demo locally using localhost as the host. However once I deploy it my HCP instance I'm at a loss as to how I would point another device at the correct server/IP and port?

Things I have tried : using websockets instead, cloud connector, just using node.js and a db tunnel which isn't great as the tunnel closes after 24hrs.

If someone even knew what areas I could research to get a greater understanding of it, it would be helpful. HCP is just an enormous platform. Unfortunately socket.io really is the only thing I could use in this case, so this question is more about the routing of urls and ports than socket.io.

Comment: Hi Moe, can you please be more specific about your use-case? Especially what kind of components you have and how they should interact with each other. For me, it's not 100% clear yet of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi. Sorry about the late response, I didn't get any notification about your comment. So I have the HCP instance running as mostly just a DB and interface, have some websocket stuff in the interface that will be going to a node server (we will call this MAIN), MAIN would return  socket.io messages to other node servers (APPS) running on various machines. Basically what I wanted to acheive above is to eliminate the MAIN server and have the HCP instance communicate directly with the APPS.

Comment: Continued from above : I need to work out if you can create a server with an IP and port on a HCP as I also have an external device that communicates solely through http requests and the only parameters you can set on it is IP and port. Ha, I imagine this actually makes it more confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about socket.io, but based on your comments above, it shouldn't be difficult to put in the correct address for your clients. Every Java app you deploy on HANA Cloud Platform has a unique URL available. And in case you use HTTP you would need to use port **80** for your clients, for HTTPS port **443**.

[image]